# Delete object keys and return conditional type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, union-types, conditional-types

I have two interfaces to describe the different messages

```js
interface MessageA {
  timestamp: number
}

interface MessageB {
  name: string
}
```

and an interface to describe their common fields

```js
interface CommonMessage {
  text: string
  url: string
}
```

And I combine them into a new type by adding extra fields with the type declared using `const enum`

```js
const enum Type {
  A,
  B,
}

type CombinedMessage =
  | (MessageA & CommonMessage & { type: Type.A })
  | (MessageB & CommonMessage & { type: Type.B })
```

Besides, I define a type that removes the common fields in the `CombinedMessage`

```js
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends string & keyof T> = T extends any ? Omit<T, K> : never
type Message = DistributiveOmit<CombinedMessage, keyof CommonMessage | 'type'>
```

Now, I want to define a function to convert `CombinedMessage` into `Message`.

```js
const omit = <T, K extends string & keyof T>(value: T, keys: readonly K[]): DistributiveOmit<T, K> => {
  const ret = { ...value }
  for (const key of keys) {
    delete ret[key]
  }
  return ret
}
```

After `omit` function is defined, I can define

```js
function removeCommonFields(combinedMessage: CombinedMessage): Message {
  return omit(combinedMessage, ['text', 'url', 'type'])
}
```

to get what I want.

However, `Typescript` compiler shows that the line

```js
return ret
```

in function `omit` has errors that

```js
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DistributiveOmit<T, K>'.ts(2322)
```

It shows that `ret` here is the generic type `T`, so I cannot return as the type `DistributiveOmit<T, K>`.

It seems that `delete` operation do nothing for the type of `ret`.

Currently, I use `return ret as unknown as DistributiveOmit<T, K>` to avoid the compiler showing error; however, I want to avoid using type assertion as possible as I can.

Is there any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less a design limitation of TypeScript. You can't really avoid [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) here.

The compiler *defers* evaluation of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on an as-yet-unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, and thus it cannot really verify that anything is assignable to such types.

And while `Omit<X, K>` is seen as a supertype of `X`, and thus `Omit<X, K> | Omit<Y, K> | Omit<Z, K>` would be seen as a supertype of `X | Y | Z`, the compiler does not know how to generalize that distributivity to `DistributiveOmit<T, K>` inside the body of `omit()` where `T` is unspecified.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for more compiler support with generic functions that return conditional types.  It doesn't look like there's any obvious solution to this in the near future, and even if there were it might not work in your particular example.  So for the time being, the best you can do is a type assertion (or something equivalent like a single call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)).

---

The only slight improvement I can think of would be to use `Omit<T, K>` instead of `unknown` as your intermediate asserted type:

```
return ret as Omit<T, K> as DistributiveOmit<T, K>; // no error
```

It would help catch errors where you return something other than `ret` accidentally:

```
// return "oopsie" as unknown as DistributiveOmit<T, K>; // no error
// return "oopsie" as Omit<T, K> as DistributiveOmit<T, K>; // error!
```

Which might be better than nothing, but not by much.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcwgQWQG8AoZZMYAW0zDioAcAuZEAVyoCNoSBfEkqEixEKdFlwQAQsTKt6EFhjBRQOPgMHho8JMgDCAeypVDIcdjyzykAB5glKtXLZQANo9Uh1-AQjPKyBDsVMgAKgCeDCik5PgANHJSib5gUShGXKAQACYWksgAvHIAPsgAFPl4hABkBsam5piWKHVEFOkskdEAdIS8AJSlFVXSyHWZjaPjxB3RXek9MoOaadHIACLAyqqcbJQAbhAA8lTAYAA8YfHIANJB9sE5GMg7ajMA1hARhjDhAHxFcIPSAgZ7IOAgCLIAD8yFO5yuN1ugJYIAgRygJDWYmaBUKm22Tj2hxOZ0umU42TyeLwNy+Pz+kzM0zKAHIcWz-pp-CBAsZzkCkXcQU8Xm9vJ9vr8AeUDnA3GxFOF6d8MCwoBA4DkzG5obcANoAXQGLC2bxJwCOCMu1zugMKgNiyF5gU1YCB7R63vlipQ-HIMEMUAqro9DOQMoZGAG1nIyByEDcEEgyHdBoZRrkvnIYcjHzNRN2+ytZMRdpRQIARIZDAwMMAIFWIS82CAPiBDAB3EAtwkWkvW8nClEAbmQAHoJ6xDEEoFBg3I853CwPSTaRw7kDW6w2m32NxXAXAXubiYOy7bkf9x1O5wusXJ3a5e+6D8Oj32z8X1x-rwJfAEGA2wQSgzDTCBTCOZkQAAMUbNxnnKfwsnRGkJDwFhKWpUZTTQWkYifFMX0jclkOMKk0NGG4DQ5CB7DZG42VcNxGOQDl0jZE0NBIYCQFA4BwKDQxhQAVRuAA1f5ylsLpkDKUT5OQCS8MPG4qzgKtATKDdxO3TTtPhYcJPUgy42fKBe1sUc+CAA)